# SQL syntax error using SELECT COUNT(*) OVER()

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () AS total, id, action, reason, target_id, created_at, created_by
FROM audit_log
WHERE action = 'CREATE USER'
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 150
```

returns the following error:

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() AS total FROM audit_log WHERE action = 'CREATE USER' LIMIT 50 OFFSET 150' at line 1
```

but I can't find what the error is? Can anyone help me find the santax error? I'm using Aurora MySQL

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Window functions were added in 8.x.

Comment: Engine version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.08.2 is that why? Thank you!!

Comment: Is there another way to rewrite this to work without windows functions?

Comment: You can join a subquery that gets `COUNT(*)` with a subquery that gets all the other columns.